# Odd behavior when creating new Date instances

Tags: javascript

Good day.
I've detected a bug today at work related to this situation but could not figure out the reason for this behavior.

Why does:

```
new Date(undefined)
```

returns an invalid date, but:

```
new Date(null)
```

returns a valid one (Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect it's because

```
Number(undefined)
```

is `NaN` while

```
Number(null)
```

is `0`. The `Date` constructor attempts to force its argument to be a number. If that number is `NaN`, you get an invalid date.  If it's `0` however, it's the epoch date.

If you want to be safe and you're having problems with `undefined` values sneaking through, you could always do something like

```
var theDate = new Date( whatever || 0 );
```

However the usefulness of those dates seems questionable.

Comment: Is the reference for 'null' being fetched for the constructor resolution? That would explain why typeof null === 'object'. Assuming of course the reference for the null "object" is 0

Comment: But, `new Date()` and `new Date(undefined)` should be same, but seems that `Date` constructor check `arguments` length and then trying to convert `arguments[0]` to integer.

Comment: @Givi they're not quite the same - when you explicitly pass `undefined` to a function, then in that function `arguments.length` will be 1, not 0.